# Brisk walking and weight loss calculation

Tags: weight-loss, walking

Suppose that i need 1000 kcal a day as BMR and i am a sendentary person. I eat at max 1000 kcal a day. If i start brisk walking for 500 kcal a day, that would mean, considering a 70% of energy source during brisk walking coming from fat burning, that i burn 350 kcal from fat. The caloric deficit will be compensated by fat burning again, so, let's consider another 350 kcal from fat. That would sum up to 700 kcal from fat during a time span of 24h. After ten days, i should lost one kilogram of fat (1kg = 7000 kcal), three in a month. Is this calculation *in principle* correct?

Comment: What is the point of your question? what are you basing your numbers off of?

Answer (score 3):

**No**

> The caloric deficit will be compensated by fat burning again, so, let's consider another 350 kcal from fat.

This is not what happens. Your caloric deficit was generated by the brisk walk. If you were to eat an additional 500 calories, then the fat/energy burned during the brisk walk will be replenished. At the end of the day your calories burned / fat lost will be net 0.

Technically, in your scenario, you are in a 500 calories deficit by the end of your walk, but you have to eat *eventually*. If you waited the next day and ate 1500 calories throughout the day while only burning only 1000 because you didn't do the walk, then you are back to a net 0 deficit.

Calories burned is an accumulation of work performed throughout the day. The cause of that work doesn't matter. That accumulation is called your [Total Daily Energy Expenditure (TDEE)](https://www.encyclopedia.com/sports/sports-fitness-recreation-and-leisure-magazines/total-daily-energy-expenditure). Walking, running, standing, digesting, breathing, heart beating, thinking and so on is all included in this.

Calories consumed comes from all the food you eat.

A calorie deficit occurs when the TDEE is higher than the calories consumed. How much of that is fat, glycogen, or lean mass is near impossible to accurately calculate and frankly not worth it. It will always be *some* portion of those three so being in a caloric deficit over time will ensure fat loss.

Comment: And what if i do eat always 1000 kcal a day? It is possible that i don't understand the concept of "calorie deficit". I tought was something like: i eat 1000 kcal a day and consume (overall) 1500.

Comment: @luke Then you will be in a 500 calorie deficit every day.  Over the course of a week, you would burn 10,500 calories and consumed 7,000 putting you at a 3,500 calorie deficit (10,500 - 7,000 = 3,500).

Comment: Now whether or not you *actually burned* that much is another issue.  A 500 calorie walk is actually pretty long, and step counters aren't known for their accuracy.

Comment: This is a good answer. Note that energy expenditure will adapt in ways you don't have direct control over, so though this calculation works in the short term, it is dynamic in the long term.

Comment: @michael So what i wrote is correct in the short term, but in the long term probably not. My point was that creating a caloric deficit with (a lot) of moderate physical activity, like brisk walking, will help you burn fat from caloric deficit AND from the type of physical activity itself, since more intense physical activities will burn more glucose than fat. So, for the same amout of calories burned, an activity like brisk walking is better than runnning for weight loss, for example.

Comment: @luke although lower intensity exercise burns a higher percentage of fat, higher intensity probably burns more total. Any exercise is good and will likely improve body composition (more muscle, less fat at the same weight) as long as you are eating well (not hydrating with gatorade). Intentional caloric deficits have not been shown to cause maintainable weight loss in the long term.

Comment: Higher intensity cardio burns more glycogen at the time, but since there's no more glycogen, fat usage increases for the remaining day.  It ends up pretty much being the same in the end.

Comment: @michael "Intentional caloric deficits have not been shown to cause maintainable weight loss in the long term."  That's not true at all. TDEE will go down for various reasons as weight goes down, but the remedy to that is to lower calories further to maintain the deficit. There is a limit because at a certain point it's just suffering. You can then "reverse diet" by slowly increasing calories, and over time your TDEE will increase back to normal. Explaining the mechanisms as to why is more complex for a comment section and it's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: "Fat Loss Forever" by Dr. Layne Norton and Peter Baker do a great job at explaining the complex relationship with one's TDEE and calories. Other good sources are Alan Aragon, Martin MacDonald, Dr. Mike Israetel, and Dr. Spencer Nadolsky.

Comment: @DeeV Let's take this to chat, where you can show me the studies where weight loss was maintained (spoiler: they don't exist)